React native TextInput selectionColor not working
The cursor color does not change using the selectedColor property.
It was working normally until I updated to expo sdk 51 and tested on ios 17.4.1. Still works on android.
There is no error message, it just doesn't change the color. The react native documentation for TextInput only indicates the use of selectionColor (for both ios and android).
I tried using other colors besides "#000000" and it still has the iOS default color.
If you need more information about the project please let me know.
<TextInput selectionColor={"#000000"} cursorColor={"#000000"} maxLength={7}/>

"expo": "^51.0.2",
"react": "18.2.0"

I've encountered this same issue. I'm not using Expo but I am using the same version of react (18.2.0). The react-native version I'm using is 0.74.1 and the iOS minimum deployment version is 12.0.

I encountered this issue on react-native:0.74.1. The react-native:0.74.2 release notes say the following. After updating to at least react-native:0.74.2 the issue was resolved. Hope this helps you as well!

Fixed an issue where the selectionColor prop was not being applied on the TextInput component. (2bde626a9f by @robinshin)

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.74.2
Special thanks to @Baias and the members of the Reactiflux Community's #help-react-native discord channel.
